# Iterating over text files in a folder and creating dataframe with 1 file / row in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration, text-mining

I have a corpus of 14K text files that I want to read in to a dataframe. I want each file to be a unique row in said dataframe. Here's what I have so far:

import glob 
import os 
import pandas as pd 
os.chdir("/Users/Wintermute/Desktop/senior_thesis/topic_models/corpus/")

content = pd.DataFrame() 
i = 0

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        i += 1
        print(i)
        content[i,] = f.readlines()

df = pd.DataFrame(content)
df.to_csv("corpus_article_by_line.csv")

When I run the program it acts as I would expect for the first 5 text files, but then I get a valueError: length of values does not match length of index.

Full error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Wintermute/PycharmProjects/cs4/test.py", line 13, in 
    content[i,] = f.readlines()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2419, in **setitem**
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2485, in _set_item
6
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2656, in _sanitize_column
    value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2800, in _sanitize_index
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: Ensuring that the file was not blank and using read() instead of readlines() fixed the problem: statinfo = os.stat(file) | if statinfo.st_size > 0: | content.append(f.read())

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a non-uniform number of lines in your text files?

Comment: I didn't realize how readlines() worked and yes, the issues was the formatting of the content of the text files.